# Unable to call a (void) function programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm having a strange problem. I'm trying to call a `void` function programmatically, the `void` function is the seguent:

```
- (void)expView:(ExpandableTableView *)expView didExpandAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    /* CODE HERE */
}
```

so, if I correctly understand it, this function takes two parameters: `expView`, of class `ExpandableTableView`, and `index` of `NSInteger` type. If you're wondering what `ExpandableTableView` is it's a subclass of `UITableView` imported from [this](https://github.com/Zedenem/ExpandableTableView) GitHub project, which I use to create a `UITableView`with expandable cell in my project.

The problem I'm having is that I can't call that void function programmatically with:

```
[self expView:nameOfTheExpandableTableView didExpandAtIndex:1];
```

And I can't figure out why. Also, the UITableView which I need to expand programmatically wasn't created using Storyboard, so I assigned it an "outlet" with a `for in` cycle in the `viewDidLoad`

This is my code:

```
@interface ViewController () {
    ExpandableTableView *customizedTableView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    /* HERE I SEARCH FOR ALL EXPANDABLETABLEVIEW(s) */
    for (customizedTableView in [self.view subviews]) {
        if ([customizedTableView isKindOfClass:[ExpandableTableView class]]) {
            [self expView:customizedTableView shouldExpandAtIndex:1];
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL)expView:(ExpandableTableView *)expView shouldExpandAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    /* THIS FUNCTION IS CALLED JUST BEFORE THE VOID ONE */
    return index;
}

- (void)expView:(ExpandableTableView *)expView didExpandAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {

}
```

The code works, in fact if I try to use breakpoints to check that all gets called [even the void function] but nothing happens.

Can you help me?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  You title says you can't call the function, but your last sentence says it is called.

Comment: So no compile issues, and viewDidLoad isn't called?

Comment: @Wain Yes, no compiling issues and the viewDidLoad is correctly called

Comment: @rdelmar Yes I can call it but nothing happens, maybe I'm calling it incorrectly?

Comment: You also call `shouldExpandAtIndex`, not `didExpandAtIndex`, and return an integer instead of a BOOL. It really isn't clear what you're trying to do... These look like delegate methods anyway

Comment: @Stuart yes, but when I "tap" on a cell of the UITableView the same method get's called [empty] and the cell expands

Comment: The project your link to (ExpandableTableView) doesn't appear to define an API for programmatically expanding table view cells. It seems what you are doing in your code is calling the delegate callback and expecting something to happen. Delegate methods are called from the ExpandableTableView instance to ask you (the delegate) whether a particular cell should expand (`expView:shouldExpandAtIndex:`), or to notify you when a cell has expanded (`expView:didExpandAtIndex:`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The project you link to](https://github.com/Zedenem/ExpandableTableView) doesn't appear to define an API for programmatically expanding table view cells.

It seems what you are doing in your code is calling the delegate callback and expecting something to happen. Delegate methods are called from the `ExpandableTableView` instance to ask *you* (the delegate) whether a particular cell should expand (`expView:shouldExpandAtIndex:`), or to notify you when a cell has expanded (`expView:didExpandAtIndex:`).

What the class does appear to provide is a delegate method for setting certain cells to be expanded "by default" (on initial load, and following a call to `-reloadData` as far as I can tell): `-expandableTableView:sectionExpandedByDefault:`.

So, for example, if you only wanted every other cell to be expanded when the table view loads, you might implement the delegate method like so:

```
- (BOOL)expandableTableView:(ExpandableTableView *)expandableTableView sectionExpandedByDefault:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section % 2 == 0) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

If that isn't suitable for what you need, you will probably have to dive into the implementation and write it yourself (shouldn't be too difficult since the logic is already there for tapping on a cell).

Answer (score 1):

You actually never call the method, you say:

> I try to use breakpoints to check that all gets called [even the void function] but nothing happens.

What do you exactly mean? That a breakpoint inside `expView:didExpandAtIndex:` is actually triggered? If that's true (I don't see how it ever could been called, but anyway) it's logical that nothing happens, because there's no code in there.

The other thing is that you're doing nothing with the returned index from `expView:shouldExpandAtIndex:`

In short, your code is a bit strange.
I could help you further if you more clearly explain what you're trying to do.